# How to put caption on top of the table with packege longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable

I used package `longtable` for make table in mamy pages.

With package `supertabular` we have `\topcaption` for caption on the top of table.

I can't use `\topcaption` in `\begin{longtable}   \end{longtable}` .

Help me put caption on the top of the table.

Answer (score 9):

```
\begin{longtable}{...}
\caption{...}\\   % it is internally like \multicolumn
... the tabular rows ...
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Can i write \caption{} \\ \hline ?

Comment: @user41499 yes did you try it? as in a normal table environment `\caption` can go anywhere, at the top at the bottom or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @user41499: `\caption` is like `\multicolumn` and _must end_ with a `\\` which, of course  can have a `\hline` or whatever which is allowed for tabular line ends.